# PHP When a folder is created in a directory create a link to that directory

Tags: php

I have absolutely no idea where to start with this idea.

What I want to do is:

Have a directory: folder/

Then when any folder is created within that folder, a link is automatically created, linking to the newly created folder and have the link have the name of the folder.

Then after all that, I want to have a file created, named (thefoldername.php) at the root of my server.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: this looks more like a bash script than a php script. php can't create files in your root, unless your web user has root access, which is unlikely.

Comment: _I have absolutely no idea_ - likewise. Can you run through that again? Do you mean the server root or the web root (they are different)? And what is `(thefoldername.php)` supposed to be?

Comment: use glob() to get a list of the directories process from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking:

```
$path='folder' ;

foreach (glob($path . "/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir){

echo '<a href="'.$dir.'">'.$dir.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is working!  
But it's returning the folder name as 'folder/2folder' instead of just the '2folder'.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of assumptions:
1) your server has write permissions to the webroot.
2) you've captured the name of the folder are creating (e.g. tmp)
3) you want a link added to some file in webroot.

you can then use mkdir to make the directory. say in $path.'/'.$tmp where $tmp is name of newly created folder and $path is folder/

then create a file like with file_put_contents (contents of file ??? perhaps including a link to the new file.) this part is unclear.

Comment: you may want to do some error checking to see if mkdir works (or if the dir already exists) if it does then your hosed or pick a new name for the new folder.